# How to insert theorems to tcolorbox?

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox

I trying to insert a theorem to `tcolorbox` without title.

Here is MWE (with LyX):

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}}
\addto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\theoremname}{משפט}}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{משפט}

\begin{document}
%\tcbox{ <=============================
\begin{thm}
as
\end{thm}

%} <=============================
\end{document}
```

Now, if you remove the lines with the `<=============================` it wont compile, do you know why and how can I fix it?

(I tried to remove some code lines but then it always give me errors)

Thank you!

::Edit:: 
Here is other MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

%\tcbox{ <=============================
\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be 
\end{theorem}
%} <=============================
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get a lot of erros when compiling your code. as you posted it here, does it compile without errors on your computer? If yes, then please ignore my comment. If no, then I think the origin of your problem is not what you suspect. You should probably go through your code line-by-line and get rid of all useless parts that could cause erros (e.g. I don't  see why you have `\makeatletter` there). Also it's hard for others to try and help you because to compile your code they have to install all those fonts etc, eventhough this seems not essential for your question.

Comment: At my computer it compiles... @sheß

Comment: Yes... Maybe it's something at LyX?

Comment: Could also be problem on my side. Either way, your MWE loads a lot of things (fonts, etc) that are seem not essential to reproduce your problem but make it impossible for some (me) to try and help you with your problem. You might increase your chances to get feedback by minimizing your MWE further.

Comment: Other option, if it's ok for you, is to put MWE of theorem with tcolorbox (without title)

Comment: I'm putting another  MWE....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use `\begin{tcolorbox}...\end{tcolorbox}` it works for me.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox} %<=============================
\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be 
\end{theorem}
\end{tcolorbox} %<=============================
\end{document}
```

[image]

Based on the [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) it seems  unlikely that this approach would constrain you compared to `\tcbox`:
[image]

Let me know if there's a reason that does not work for you